# How do you remove a number of characters from a parsed string?

Tags: arduino-ide

Using this code - `advertisedDevice.getServiceDataUUID().toString().c_str());` returns the following string -
`0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

How can I adjust the code to do that it omits the first nine characters leaving only -
`0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

Thank you.

Comment: not an arduino question ... it is a general programming question

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Even if this question is about general C++ programming, this might help other Arduino users, too. Better ask at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) the next time. ;-)*

The result of your chain of method calls returns a pointer to non-writable `char`s. You can add any offset to this, in the range from 0 to the number of characters.

In your case:

```cpp
const char* result = advertisedDevice.getServiceDataUUID().toString().c_str() + 9;
```